# Intermolecular interaction Van Der Waals

Tags: intermolecular-forces, van-der-waals-behavior

In the [empirical demonstration of the Van der Waals equation at Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/gases-and-kinetic-molecular-theory/non-ideal-gas-behavior/v/van-der-waals-equation), they made a demonstration of the real volume, for example, it was said that it has to be larger than the ideal volume, since the size of the molecules is not disregarded, hence it would be:

$$ V_{\text{ideal}} = V_{\text{real}} + nb $$

Where, $ b $ was said to be related to the size of the molecule.

But why don't I also include intermolecular interaction? Depending on it, the volume may even be smaller.

Comment: How would interatomic interactions affect the volume? Can you please elaborate on how you think interatomic interactions affect the volume?

Comment: Interatomic interactions will affect the pressure and not volume.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Intermolecular interactions can cause attraction or repulsion, changing the volume, right?

Comment: Atomic interactions can't change the volume of a gas. Just assume if they did decrease the volume than wouldn't there be vacuum spaces inside a gas.

Comment: If you see the full van der Waals equation, the parameter a is associated with the correction for intermolecular attraction.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar I disagree. In an attraction for example, there would still be vacuum spaces, they would just be a little bit smaller

Comment: You are confusing vacuum with interatomic void.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar what would be the interatomic void?

Comment: Let's say it is mobile, a piston, the kinetic energy (with the addition of heat, say) overcomes the interatomic attraction, and the volume increases. If you increase the attraction while increasing the kinetic energy, which is bizarre, you would even have that he said

Comment: @NisargBhavsar To say that interaction does not change volume is absurd. If it were in this logic, the compressibility factor Z would always be greater than 1, and guess what, even if the real gas does not have a negligible volume, the compressibility factor is often less than 1, due to interactions

Comment: Compressibility and Volume are two different quantities. Compressibility does depend on interatomic interactions. But that doesn't mean volume depends on interatomic interactions.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar z is real volume/ideal volume

Comment: *Volume ratio at the same pressure and to assure that you will have to include $a$. $Z= \frac{(P+ \frac{an}{V^2}) (V-nb) }{nRT}$. And I just noticed your equation you mentioned is also incorrect.

Comment: $V_{\text{ideal}} = V_{\text{real}} - nb$ is correct. Refer [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/149989/how-can-we-replace-volume-in-ideal-gas-equation-with-v-nb)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123196/discussion-between-nisarg-bhavsar-and-behemooth).

Comment: I think you got something backward: the volume V is always "the real volume", no matter what gas you have. But to obtain an expression that looks like the ideal-gas you can make the substitution $V_{ideal}=V_{real}-nb$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intermolecular attraction can reduce the volume, in the same way that increasing the pressure can lower the volume (Boyle's law).

One way to see the effect is to take the derivative of the volume, as given by the van der Waals (vdW) equation, with respect to the attractive parameter $a.$

The vdW equation is

$$\left(p+\frac{a}{\bar{V}^2}\right)(\bar{V}-b)=RT\tag{1}$$

Ignore for simplicity the excluded volume term $b,$ so that

$$p\bar{V}=RT-\frac{a}{\bar{V}}\tag{2}$$

Then the derivative of the volume wrt $a$ is

$$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial a} \right)_{p,T} = \frac{\bar{V}}{a-p\bar{V}^2}=-(RT)^{-1}\tag{3}$$

In essence what this result says is that the volume decreases as you increase the parameter $a.$